# setState function undefined in React using ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I dont understand a syntax difference between vanilla javascript and ES6 in a React Application. 
My first code that doesn't work is

```
class App extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {videos:[]};

YTSearch({key: API_KEY,term :'surfboards'},function(videos){
  this.setState({videos : videos});
});
}
```

This gives a 'Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined' error in the console

but changing the syntax to

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY,term :'surfboards'},(videos)=>{
   this.setState({videos : videos});
});
```

fixes the problem. Isn't both the same thing(I may be wrong).Using

```
function(videos){}
```

and

```
(videos) => {}
```

I am not comfortable with javascript so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to how `this` is bound.

When using an arrow function `this` is still bound to your `App` class.

However, when you use the `function` keyword `this` is bound to that function.

As per MDN

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value.

Using the `function` keyword you could take two approaches.

Firstly,

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY,term :'surfboards'}, function(videos){
  this.setState({
      videos : videos
   });
}.bind(this));
```

or else you could do:

```
//assign this to new variable that to use when setting state
let that = this;

YTSearch({key: API_KEY,term :'surfboards'}, function(videos){
  that.setState({
      videos : videos
   });
});
```

Comment: If you dont mind would you be able to show how I will write the above code using the function keyword please.

Comment: @Buttersnips see updated answer, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Done.Sorry new to posting here.

Answer (score 2):

*this* refers to function.
I suggest using ES6 arrow function:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {videos:[]};

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY,term :'surfboards'}, (videos) => {
      this.setState({videos : videos});
    });
  }
}
```

It's because arrow function does not create its own *this*, the *this* value of the enclosing execution context is used.
You can also store reference to *this* in variable (or bind function):

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    var _this = this;

    this.state = {videos:[]};

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY,term :'surfboards'}, function(videos){
      _this.setState({videos : videos});
    });
  }
}
```